# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar la posición de una imagen recortada con "clip:rect"?

Tags: html

Se considera que la etiqueta `<img>` de color amarillo es una imagen. Empleando `clip:rect(50px,60px,200px,20px)`, la imagen se posiciona lejos de los márgenes. La pregunta es

¿cómo se pueda situar de forma automática a los margenes, es decir, todas las imágenes que recorte, se posicionen de forma normal, como si realmente no estuviesen recortadas?

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(50px,60px,200px,20px);
}
```

```html
<img style="background-color:yellow;" width="100" height="140">
```

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `clip` está deprecada, por lo que te aconsejo que no la uses para conseguir lo que necesitas:

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
> browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
> Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may
> break at any time.

En su lugar usaría un `<div>` que hiciera de marco, con las medidas que necesites para el "recorte" y a través de la propiedad `overflow: hidden` hacer que lo que sobrepase esas medidas desaparezca. Luego, puedes jugar con el `margin` de la imagen que tienes dentro del marco para calibrar que sección de la imagen deseas que se visualice.

En mi ejemplo incluyo dos secciones de la imagen, una sin calibrar y la otra calibrada para que muestre otra sección distinta de la imagen.

```css
#contenedor-marcos {
  display: flex;
}

.marco {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.movido img {
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor-marcos">
  <div class="marco">
    <img src="https://marvelcrowd.com/media/Captura-de-pantalla-2015-10-13-a-las-12.28.25.png">
  </div>

  <div class="marco movido">
    <img src="https://marvelcrowd.com/media/Captura-de-pantalla-2015-10-13-a-las-12.28.25.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Si tu imagen es un **svg** puedes usar la propiedad `clip-path` que es la que sustituye a `clip`, aunque no todos los navegadores la soportan por tratarse de una tecnología experimental.

**Referencias:** [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip), [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal, lo que quieres lograr es que una imagen se muestre dentro de unos límites (p.e. 100px x 140px) ocupando todo el espacio y que se adapte a éste de forma que siempre muestre la parte central.

Se logra con las propiedades `object-fit` y `object-position` de esta forma:

### En el html

Necesitas un contenedor para la imagen además de la imagen en sí:

```
<div class="imagen-de-perfil">
    <img src='https://robohash.org/random'>
</div>
```

### En el css

Determinas las dimensiones del contenedor y luego cómo va a adaptarse la imagen a él:

```
.imagen-de-perfil {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
}

.imagen-de-perfil img {
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Puedes variar los parámetros para que la imagen se muestre completa (`object-fit: contain`) o para colocarla de otro modo (por ejemplo, que siempre se vea la esquina superior izquierda `object-position: top left;`)

Hay amplia documentación en la red sobre estas propiedades CSS, así que no tendrás problema en encontrar ejemplos.